# the same pretrained model with same input , running multiple times gives different outputs

Tags: pytorch

I load a pretrained Resnet152 from torchvision. I evaluate the model multiple times with the same input image, but each time the output is different. It's very strange. Anyone knows what is the reason? My code is

```
from torchvision import transforms
import torch
from torchvision import models
from PIL import Image

# load a pretrained model
model = models.resnet152(pretrained=True)

# load a image and preprocess it
preprocessor = transforms.Compose([            
 transforms.Resize(256),                    
 transforms.CenterCrop(224),                
 transforms.ToTensor(),                     
 transforms.Normalize(                     
 mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],                
 std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]                  
 )])

input_image = Image.open('lion2.jpg')
input_tensor = preprocessor(input_image)
input_batch = torch.unsqueeze(input_tensor, 0)

# run multiple times and print output 
for k in range(5):
    model.train()
    out = model(input_batch)

    model.eval()
    out2 = model(input_batch)

    print(out2[0][:10].cpu().detach())
```

The output are

```
tensor([ 0.4722, -2.1463, -0.5993, -0.3880, -2.6292,  1.9123, -1.7939, -0.3289,
        -0.3189,  0.5306])
tensor([ 0.4407, -2.0370, -0.7397, -0.4447, -2.6059,  1.9052, -1.9715, -0.6495,
        -0.5361,  0.2618])
tensor([ 0.3874, -1.9249, -0.8254, -0.5408, -2.5266,  1.8302, -2.1151, -0.8739,
        -0.7206,  0.0478])
tensor([ 0.3150, -1.8490, -0.9004, -0.6544, -2.4615,  1.7409, -2.2083, -1.0194,
        -0.8352, -0.1017])
tensor([ 0.2310, -1.7754, -0.8858, -0.7081, -2.3238,  1.5943, -2.2625, -1.1185,
        -0.9551, -0.2954])
```

(If I remove either model.train() or model.eval(), the output keep constant. )

Comment: So just to confirm with what you've provided as code,  `out2` is the tensor that is printed, correct having called `model.eval()` prior to the inference call?

Answer (score 2):

The model `torchvision.models.resnet152` contains batch normalization layers with `track_running_stats` set to `True`. This [means](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html) that whenever the model is called in training mode (i.e., when `model.train()` is set), the `running_mean` and `running_var` parameters of such batch normalization layers get updated to include the data of the batch passed in that call.

In your example, each time you call the model under `model.train()` in the loop, this causes the `running_mean` and `running_var` parameters of all the batch normalization layers to be updated. These are then freezed at the updated values when you call `model.eval()`, and used in the second forward pass, which causes the outputs to be different.

Since you are passing exactly the same inputs every time in the loop, it implies that the `running_mean` and `running_var` will converge to a constant after a large number of iterations. You can check that as a result the outputs in `eval()` mode eventually become identical.

The standard way of evaluating networks typically involves calling `model.eval()` once and using it over the entire test set, and so does not exhibit this apparent discrepancy.